# Vertically center two divs inside a wrapper (with dynamic content and content below the wrapper)

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to center two divs with dynamic heights inside a dynamic wrapper... I've been playing with all sorts of tricks to try and get this working cross-browser to no avail, does anyone have a suggestion?  See graphic for explanation!  The purple block is another block on content I want to sit 20px below the dynamic wrapper.

[image: Question explanation]

- NOTE:  For the note to the left of the red box, I meant to say "It should scale to be as tall as whichever contained div (green or red) is taller.
- I also do not know whether the red or green box will be taller - just that the green box's height is dynamic and the red's height is fixed.

Comment: would you accept a jquery solution ?

Comment: Potentially if it was lightweight, again the big issue is that I don't know whether the red or green box will be taller.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` + `vertical-align: middle` on the blocks, so they would be aligned just like you want them to.

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/Tky8T/

Even more: the height of the red div can be dynamic too!

Comment: I like this implementation, but if the text is long, it does not wrap correctly onto the next line.

Comment: I couldn't manage to make it work. HTML can surprise me even after 18 years of working together.

Comment: @AttilaFulop I had a problem and it was not working for a long time... then I realized that since I had `<div>` tags I used `float: left;` and that's what prevented the `inline-block` from working properly. Only the browsers don't tell you!

Answer (score 3):

If you make the wrapper `div` to be `posititon: relative`. Then have the green `div` to be `position: absolute`, you can make it vertically centered. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/56Ase/

Comment: There's a problem with this... I don't know whether the red or green box will be taller.

Comment: Also this relies on me knowing the height of the green box (top: 50%, margin-top: -halfheight;).  I won't know what the height of the green box is.

Answer (score 1):

So I've had a quick poke at your question, it's not a very big jQuery solution, in fact it's so simple that even i could do it !

What i did was worked out which div is bigger dynamically (i.e. is red or green bigger), we then ignore the bigger div and work out the correct vertical margin for the smaller div.

View this example for a better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/6fN48/

## CSS

```
 #wrapper
{ width: 400px; border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px; margin: 0 auto; }

#wrapper .red
{ width: 195px; float: left; border: 1px solid red; }

#wrapper .green
{ width: 195px; float: right; border: 1px solid green; }
```

## jQuery

```
var r = $('#wrapper .red').outerHeight();
var g = $('#wrapper .green').outerHeight();
var w = $('#wrapper').outerHeight();

/* calculate which is bigger and apply the margin to that element */

/* is the red or green div bigger? */
if(r > g){

    /* ok red is bigger, then work out the top margin to apply onto green */
    var x = (w - g) / 2;

    /* apply CSS to the green div */
    $('#wrapper .green').css({ 'margin-top' : x + 'px' });

} else if(r < g){

     /* ok green is bigger, then work out the top margin to apply onto red*/
    var x = (w - r) / 2;

    /* apply CSS to the red div */
    $('#wrapper .red').css({ 'margin-top' : x + 'px' });

}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="red">
        Lorem ....
    </div>
    <div class="green">
        Lorem ipsum dolor ...
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />
</div>
```

I hope this helps, the only other way is to use css positioning with a known height, which obviously is not dynamic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use flex?

```
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
       -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
       -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
```