# Create a list like this

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a list like this one using CSS:

[image]

First I tried using lists, but everytime I tried to align the two paragraph with the bullet, went wrong.

How can i do this ?

[Link to what I'm trying now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301334/vertically-center-two-divs-inside-a-wrapper-with-dynamic-content-and-content-be)

Comment: post the code please..

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle. It would be easier to debug jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with lists:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <div class="box">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Headline</h2>
                <small>Description is small.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.box > :first-child {
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
}

.box > :not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 60px;
}

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

small {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/enk9D/1/

Comment: The `div.box` can be removed and the rule can be replaced by `ul.list > li`.

Comment: Wow this works!! I didn't know what that ">" sign does. Learning day by day guys! Thank you a lot

EDIT: I also learned today that my title is not that clear :/

Comment: Hello there again! Now i'm dealing with different images as bullets, I tried using 
`code`
.box > li:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(img/shop-icon.png); 
 }
`code`

But doesn't work at all! Any head ups?

Comment: The box is inside the `li` element, thus it has to be `li:nth-child(2) > .box`.