# Vertically align an inline-block next to an inline-block that is taller

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align the image .b so that it's in the center of the text (vertically).

I think I understand vertical-align, and it does not help me because it aligns according to the baseline of .b, which is near the bottom of the #container.

What is the correct practice to do so? I would like to avoid setting a margin from the top.
I basically want to align according to the parent container height and not the baseline, is it possible/right?

codepen:
http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/vEONaJ

html:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {  
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 0;  
}

#container > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-image:  url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f4/Free_Blue_Star.jpg)
}

.b {
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically center two divs inside a wrapper (with dynamic content and content below the wrapper)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301334/vertically-center-two-divs-inside-a-wrapper-with-dynamic-content-and-content-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `vertical-align: middle;` on both .a and .b and that will work.

you could of course just give .b a padding and a background image with a background position of `left center` while removing .a